# При условии(,) что

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужна ли запятая перед «что» в выделенном фрагменте?

*Можно следующие правила разделить на две группки: к 1-й мы таки отнесём чередования «клан – клон, гар – гор, твар – твор», т. к. если там на этот корень падает ударение, то пишем всегда, за исключением пары слов, «о»; ко второй группоньке мы отнесём «зар – зор» и на него обратим, навек запомнив, пристальное внимание, **поскольку в нём мы всегда, при условии(,) что ударение падает не на корень, пишем** «а», но, однако, не «о».*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147763/discussion-on-question-by-pumpkin-777---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за "секреты". Если что вспомните, добавьте тогда.

Comment: @Sharon А давайте возвращать все комментарии обратно. Тогда модераторы сдадутся и перестанут сносить все комментарии (они не смотрят на содержание, смотрят только на количество!). Это за минуту можно сделать. Как вам идея?

Comment: Плохая идея, модераторов не слушаться себе дороже.  Эти комментарии потом пропадут со временем, если чат не посещается?

Comment: @Sharon Раньше пропадали. Ссылки начинали выдавать ошибку. А как сейчас, не знаю. Но из-за неактивности, как и раньше, чат замораживается. Модераторы не уважают наш труд, не ценят время и усилия, которые мы затрачиваем на написание комментариев (иногда у меня очень много времени уходит на один комментарий). Понятно, если комментарии вообще не по теме. А в удалении всего подряд  логики нет, кому не надо, не станут читать комментарии. И в учитывании удалённых сообщений логики нет. Стоило бы попробовать мою идею, не надо бояться идти против системы, вы же знаете :)

Comment: Выгонят...вот и весь поход против системы. Мне тоже не нравится удаление ценных комментариев, иногда в них проходит основное обсуждение вопроса. Но надо удаление комментариев на Мете обсуждать.

Comment: @Sharon Да никто не выгонит, не боись. Уже обсуждал, не удалось. Мол, дискуссионные комментарии вредят пользователям и не несут пользы. Хм, а ваш комментарий про секреты заставит людей перейти в чат, хитрый приёмчик :)

Comment: Ну тогда выхода нет, если уже обсуждали. Тогда все ценное пакуйте в чемоданы, то есть копируйте нужные материалы. Потом опубликуете их где-нибудь  как "Мои записки")) А с комментарием и правда смешно получилось, сейчас все ломанутся в чат за секретами. Но это ненадолго.

Comment: @Sharon Только с одним обсуждал, а второй добрее. Ну и речь шла только о спорах. Думал о таком, но не думаю, что на публикациях таких материалов можно заработать (пусть даже будет в десять раз интереснее).

Comment: @Sharon Это точно. Регистрируешься на сайтах, чтобы заработать, а они только и предлагают купить. Этот стих сложно понять. Ajgy ярый противник Ефремовой (здесь тире не надо по произношению, у Розенталя не всё). Так надо ещё за домен платить, хостинг ещё можно бесплатно получить (на месяц точно). И что, много у вас посетителей? Где программиста для сайта нашли?

Comment: @Sharon Это дорого. Есть и за доллар в месяц, а у вас аж 5. 20 человек в день? Наверно, большинство отсюда. А в чём смысл? И здесь можно вещать. Ну, там критики нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, как я думаю, так: *… поскольку в нём мы всегда, **при условии что ударение падает не на корень**, пишем «а», но, однако, не «о».*

1. Выбор  варианта может показаться некорректным тем пользователям, которые ориентированы [на Справочник по пунктуации](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/599/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE___%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8___%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B)

**При условии, что / если / чтобы,** союз

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «при условии, что / если / чтобы», выделяются знаками препинания. При этом первый знак препинания **ОБЫЧНО** ставится **между частями союза** (после слов «при условии»). *Наука может достичь гораздо большего, но **при условии, что** она займется человеком во всей его сложности*. И. Ефремов, Лезвие бритвы.

2. Тогда запись по словарю должна выглядеть так:  ***…поскольку в нём мы **всегда при условии, что ударение падает не на корень**, пишем «а», но, однако, не «о».***

Получится явное противоречие:  **всегда при условии**.  Поэтому запятую перед словами «при условии» надо поставить, а это уже **НЕОБЫЧНО**.  Соответственно,  запятая не ставится  **между частями союза**,  и тогда мы получаем нерасчлененный составной союз ***«при условии что».***

3. Что же такое **неприемлемое** видят пользователи в нерасчлененном союзе «при условии что»?  Ведь другие составные союзы часто не расчленяются.

Союз интересен тем, что состоит из двух частей: при условии + изъяснительный союз ЧТО, вводящий это условие. Фактически он **синонимичен союзу ЕСЛИ.**

Соответственно, возможны следующие варианты:  *Я приеду, **если** это необходимо. Я приеду **при условии, что** это необходимо. Я, конечно, приеду, **при условии что** это необходимо.*

**Сравнить:** *...поскольку в нём мы всегда, **если** ударение падает не на корень, пишем «а», но, однако, не «о».*  Здесь придаточное условия в середине предложения.

В этих примерах мы видим, что составной союз «при условии что» может расчленяться или не расчленяться. Конечно, более частотным является расчлененный союз, но возможны варианты, когда выбор **приходится делать** в пользу нерасчлененного союза.

4. Итак, обсуждение спорного вопроса можно считать законченным, а  участники дискуссии сделают свой выбор.

Comment: Тогда не пишите "правильно", пишите "предлагаю".

Comment: Нет, противоречие, если с запятой: в одной фразе говорим, что всегда, а в другой — что при условии (то есть уже не всегда).

Comment: И не забывайте, что есть союзы, у которых запятая в середине в любом случае. Возможно, здесь так. И вопрос именно об этом.

Comment: А мне вот не хочется удалять выше комментарии, потому что вы поступаете не по-человечески. Надо говорить, что удаляете комментарии. Так все делают, кроме вас.

Comment: Олид, в этих комментариях был отражен частный разговор, который другим неинтересен, поэтому не сердитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Надо говорить! Все остальные даже спрашивают, согласен ли удалить. А вы удаляете по-английски.

Comment: Извините. И обратите внимание: я вношу изменения в ответ по вашим замечаниям. Спасибо.

Comment: Это необъяснимо, но факт.

Comment: Я очень люблю критику.

Comment: Sharon, здравствуйте! Добавил два раза ***не***. Это же имелось в виду?

Comment: Наверное, спасибо вам.  Текст такой сложный...

Comment: Вас подменило НЛО? Та (с паузой и ударением, "да" не звучит, что-то интересное), то мелочь. Вы по первому изменили, а второй и третий? *Получится явное противоречие: всегда при условии* — не понимаю, у меня нет никакого противоречия.

Comment: НЛО меня давно уже подменило. Я, к примеру, могу видеть в этой конструкции двойственную природу (синтаксическую синонимию), это так интересно! Но рассказывать об этом пока не хочется)) Поэтому я сразу решила, что после  "всегда" должна быть запятая. Кстати, и автор ее тоже поставил (вопрос был про вторую запятую), поэтому что обсуждать?

Comment: Вы часто видите оазис в пустыне, которого нет. Ну, мы должны проверять пунктуацию. "При условии что" (без запятой) имеет уточняющий характер. Ну и вторая запятая под вопросом. "При условии" довольно самостоятельно, что в пользу запятой.

Comment: Мой оазис лучше, чем ваши синтаксические фантазии. А вот синтаксическая синонимия – вещь вполне реальная.

Comment: У меня нет фантазий, всегда говорю чётко и по факту. Фантазировать вы любите.